Solana OnCurve / OffCurve
I don't understand the whole curve thing.
I was trying to generate vanity addresses using the solana cli. I created a keypair, then derived the pubkey from it using solana cli. Now if I check solscan for the pubkey, it says off curve.
How can it be off curve, if the pubkey was derived from a private key? I thought off curve addresses don't have private keys?
PS: I can import these wallets just fine into phantom using the private key. Are these addresses usable?

Check solana.fm, they don't seem to have that bug. Also check out this question for more info: https://solana.stackexchange.com/questions/14566/how-can-i-determine-if-an-address-is-on-or-off-curve/14567#14567


Create a keypair solana-keygen new -o test.json
Get the pubkey solana-keygen pubkey test.json
Check the public key on solscan
Solscan displays isOnCurve attribute false for the address.
Airdrop 1 SOL solana airdrop 1 FUSuByUp4hLQv3zS6eZiQhLo9yFkCATFV8BiWgMbdX8m 
isOnCurve becomes true

It may be an error on solscan.
