How can I determine if an address is on- or off-curve?
It seems Solscan defaults to setting onCurve to false for addresses that don't have any transactions associated to it. How can I reliably check if a given address is on curve or not?

We can use the isOnCurve method of PublicKey from web3.js:
const onCurve = PublicKey.isOnCurve('ACYz3rCamFVGdub1BZ43yUnemp9PWNQBbn4KvPrrMeS1');
PS: It appears solana.fm doesn't have this bug, so can also just use that.

@Jimii check out https://docs.rs/solana-program/latest/solana_program/pubkey/struct.Pubkey.html#method.is_on_curve
